# Stop Playing Song, And Play A New One (Playing Song Won't Stop)

Tags: android

This problem isn't related to the previous one, I have a button, when pressed it plays a song, when pressed again it stops it and play the new one, Stopping the current song works well, But stopping and playing a new one isn't working well, Here's the code :

```
try {
            if(isPlaying){
                isPlaying = false;
                mMediaPlayer.pause();
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                mMediaPlayer.reset();
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(Path);
                mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                mMediaPlayer.start();

                }
            else if(!isPlaying){
                isPlaying=true;
                try {
                    mMediaPlayer.reset();
                    mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(Path);
                    mMediaPlayer.prepare();
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

isPlaying is a boolean, Nvm mind about it, Removing "pause" in "if(isPlaying)" won't do anything, What happening is it stops for a half second and resume the stopped track and start the pressed one .

What's wrong with the code ?

Comment: *But stopping and playing a new one isn't working well,*...
this is not telling us anything, we need to know **What are you expecting** and **what are you getting** as behavior in the software...

Comment: I'm expecting the following : Stopping the playing song, And playing the new pressed one, What i'm getting is : Stopping a half second, And resuming the playing song and playing beside it the pressed one (it should not resume, it should stop) .

Comment: can you post log cat warnings

Comment: I have added info logs inside the methods, First, the "!isPlaying" starts, And play the song, When pressed again, the "isPlaying" starts, and stops the music, BUT it starts it again and start the new pressed one, Here's the problem .. it's starting it again .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was playing another song and not stopping the played one, Because i didn't put the MediaPlayer instance as "static", After putting, the played song stops, and the new song play without any problems .